# Python dependencies and Docker and Crontab

Tags: python, docker, redis, cron

I'm having a strange issue when trying to run a Python script via Crontab within a Docker container. Here's the setup.

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

# Install cron and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/simple-cron
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/simple-cron
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

And a crontab file like this:

```
* * * * * root python /src/test.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

This executes correctly with no problems when I start the container. The first line of my Python file is `import redis`, which causes the script to fail, saying that the module cannot be found.

The interesting thing is that when I manually execute `docker exec -it [container_name] python test.py`, everything works exactly as expected.

What could be the issue here? I'm thinking that the requirements file isn't being installed to the right location?

Comment: Where do you install your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

With python in docker I definitely find it helpful to use a vendoring tool. Instead of copying the local site-packages, run a script or series of `RUN` commands which:

1. Establish the virtualenv
2. Activate it
3. call `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Here's an example from a script I use in dev:

```
pip3 install virtualenv;
virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=python3.6 app;
virtualenv --relocatable app;
source ./app/bin/activate;
pip3 install -r requirements.txt;
```

Comment: Since a docker container is already an isolated environment it does not give any extra advantage to use a vurtual env there. Also your answer does not seem to handle the actual problem and is just a general advice.

Comment: Since the error is that the module can't be found, I actually expect that this approach may resolve the issue. It ensures that deps are in place and it ensures that they are available to the interpreter. @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` runs commands in your home directory, not in the `WORKDIR` from your Dockerfile. `docker exec -it...` will run the specified command from the `WORKDIR`, which is `/src` in your case. My guess is you install your requirements to a location that isn't included in your `PYTHONPATH`, but is visible from your `/src` directory? As @Klaus D. pointed out, it would be helpful to know where your requirements are installed... but if my suspicion is correct, there are two easy solutions:

1. change your cron job command to `cd /src && python ...`
2. Explicitly set your `PYTHONPATH` to include wherever your requirements are being installed

To further debug this, do `docker exec -it your-container-name bash`, and then do `cd ~` to change to your home directory because that is where cron jobs run from. Once there, try running your script, and if that doesn't work, try `echo $PYTHONPATH` to start debugging your import issue.